# How to SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF inside a Netezza stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza, rowcount, nzsql

Based on NZ documentation, it seems NZSQL equivalent command NO_ROWCOUNT will suppress row count information. But how do I execute/apply it inside a NZ stored procedure?

I've tried to create and executed a NZ SP that contains the command "SET NO_ROWCOUNT" with error "expecting an identifier found a keyword".

My sample code as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.MYSP() 
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY) EXECUTE AS CALLER 
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS 
BEGIN_PROC 
DECLARE 
iTot INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
--SET NO_ROWCOUNT; 
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO iTot FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE; 
RETURN iTot; 
END; 
END_PROC;
```

Pls advise.

TQ in advance!

Comment: NO_ROWCOUNT is a display toggle specific to nzsql.  Are you able to provide a sample procedure where you are looking to suppress a row-count?

Comment: Hi Rajshekar, this is my sample SP:  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.MYSP()  
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY) EXECUTE AS CALLER  
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS  
BEGIN_PROC  
DECLARE  
 iTot INTEGER;  
BEGIN  
 --SET NO_ROWCOUNT;  
 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO iTot FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE;  
 RETURN iTot;  
END;  
END_PROC;  
TQ in advance!